# Watchkit App: slider background color

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am surprised no one asked already this question, maybe I am just thinking something wrong. But here it is: I am trying to use [WKInterfaceSlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceSlider_class/) to show some progress. The background of my app is black and I really need the background of the slider to match. It looks really bad with that dark grey default background. Isn't there really anyway to set it to replace it or simply set it to nothing?

I would accept also a no answer, but I would really like to understand why this choice in the APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are unable to set the background color of the WKInterfaceSlider. You could always do a feature request.

I think the reason behind this is that the user should be familiar with the interface elements regardless of which app he/she uses.

Tips:
You could make your own Slider via a WKInterfacePicker. Where you define the slider as an image sequence. Highly customisable and you could slide it via the digital crown.
Check out this piece of code: [Trying to get button to spin in WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014470/trying-to-get-button-to-spin-in-watchkit/31020741#31020741)